# Build Warnings - isolating COM reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, msbuild, regfreecom

I have a couple active x controls referenced in my .NET 3.5 application that we use with reg free COM. When I build the solution builds successfully but with a bunch of warnings stating "Problem isolating COM reference 'ActiveXControl': Registry key: 'path' was not imported" and so the manifest generated is incomplete.

The exact error is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets (,): 
warning MSB3179: Problem isolating COM reference 'LegaceActiveXControl': 
Registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID}\Implemented Categories\{AnotherGUID}' was not imported.
```

What's weird is that one of the active x controls is built successfully but the other one is not even though it looks like the reference properties are identical.

The only thing that I can currently think of is that I am building on a x64 bit machine. The registry path in the warnings are paths in the 64 bit portion of the registry but the active x controls are registered in the Wow6432Node.

All the projects have a target platform of x86 and framework of .NET 3.5. Is there a way to tell MSBuild to look in the 32 bit registry or is there something else I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So after playing around I'm in a new state. Before I was also getting the warning message saying "assembly wrapper for MSComctlLib could not be found". I went into the SysWow64 directory and re-registered MSComctl.ocx. After doing this and doing a clean build I no longer get that warning but now both Active X controls are receiving the warning "Problem isolating COM reference etc...". But what is even weirder is now both controls show up in the manifest. I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: You obfuscated the real error message too much to provide any diagnostic.

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets (,): warning MSB3179: Problem isolating COM reference 'LegaceActiveXControl': Registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID}\Implemented Categories\{AnotherGUID}' was not imported.

Comment: That key can't be isolated.  I seriously doubt it is a problem.